# How to calculate the level of a nth node in a binary tree?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there any proof? What is the level of the root node in a tree?

Total number of nodes in a complete binary tree is:

$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ...+k^{th} level$

clearly its a geometric series hence total number of nodes = $2^{n+1} - 1$

from above I can also see that the root node is considered to be at level $0$, is this a generic notation?

Comment: What if I want to know in which level nth node lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re numbering the nodes so that the root is node $1$, its children are nodes $2$ and $3$, their four children are nodes $4,5,6$, and $7$, and so on, then node $n$ is in level $\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$, where $\lg x$ is the binary (base two) logarithm of $x$.

Yes, the root is normally considered to belong to level $0$.

Comment: Is there any proof I can refer to?

Comment: @vivek: I don’t think that I’ve seen it written up, but it’s not hard to prove. You know that there are $2^n-1$ nodes on levels $0$ through $n-1$, and you know that there are $2^n$ nodes on level $n$. If you’re numbering the nodes one level at a time, levels $0$ through $n-1$ use up the numbers $1$ through $2^n-1$, so you start numbering the nodes on level $n$ with number $2^n$, and you finish with number $2^{n+1}-1$. The numbers assigned to the nodes on level $n$ are therefore the integers $k$ such that $2^n\le k<2^{n+1}$. Taking logs base $2$, we see that his inequality is equivalent to ...

Comment: ... $n\le\lg k<n+1$, which is exactly what it means to say that $n$ is the floor of $\lg k$.

Comment: So, let me sum this up. Node 1 belongs to level 0, node 2 and 3 belongs to level 1, node 4, 5, 6, 7 belongs to level 2 and so on, here log(4) base 2 is 2 and log(5) must be somewhat greater than 2 but its level is 2 which means we must trim down the decimal part and `floor` the number.

Comment: For $\lfloor n \rfloor$ I tend to think as if a range of numbers needs to be pulled down to a common value like in our case of calculating level. I am developing this intuition, please do let me know if I am correct.

Comment: @vivek: Yes, you have the basic idea. The base $2$ log of any node on level $n$ will be $n$ plus a fractional part less than $1$, and taking the floor gets rid of that fractional part.

Comment: I feel confident now, but I don't know why this question is off-topic? is it not mathematical?

Comment: @vivek: It’s mathematical. The problem is that some people here feel very strongly that every question should contain some statement of what the asker has already tried, and they vote to close any question that does not contain that does not contain ‘your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it’ (as it says in the close notice). This attitude is partly based on the fact that it *is* easier to give a useful answer if we know exactly where the asker is having trouble, but in some cases it’s also based on an exaggerated fear of doing people’s homework for them. I ...

Comment: ... frankly don’t think that there was any legitimate reason to close your question, and fortunately I posted my answer before the question was closed.

Comment: I agree with what you said and that's why I showed the calculations. I cannot be penalized if I don't know enough maths. Nowadays I see that the community is driven by few opinionated elements and fear that SO doesn't loose its value because of this. At least individual should be forced to leave a comment before down voting or closing. Single click decision making is dangerous.